# loop is not working when I try to read a Json file and a text file with python

Tags: python, json

I have a json file with objects and a text file with several groups (Each group have 5 numbers and I have them in a list this way: the first number of each group are in list 1, the second number of each group, are in list 2, etc). I basically have to match each object of the json with each group I created. The problem is that Im getting as result the last element from the Json. The groups from the text file are created in the correct way.

This is my code:

```
import json

NUM_LIST = 5
index = 0

def report(a, b, c, d, e, index):
    json_file = 'json_global.json'
    json_data = open(json_file)
    data = json.load(json_data)

    i = 0
    index = 0
    item = 0
    cmd = " "
    ind = 0

    for node in data:
        for i in range(0, 5):
            item = data[i]['item']
            cmd = data[i]['command']

        index+= 1

     print  item, cmd, a, b, c, d, e

f = open("Output.txt", "r")
lines = [line.rstrip() for line in f if line != "\n"]

NUM_LISTS = 5
groups = [[] for i in range(NUM_LISTS)]
listIndex = 0

for line in lines:
    if "Transactions/Sec for Group" not in line:
        groups[listIndex].append(float(line))
        listIndex += 1
        if listIndex == NUM_LISTS:
            listIndex = 0

value0 = groups[0]
value1 = groups[1]
value2 = groups[2]
value3 = groups[3]
value4 = groups[4]

for i in range(0, 5):
    a = value0[i]
    b = value1[i]
    c = value2[i]
    d = value3[i]    
    e = value4[i]
    i += 1

    report(a, b, c, d, e, index)
```

The Json file looks like:

```
[
  {
    "item": 1,
    "command": "AA"
  },
  {
    "item": 2,
    "command":   "BB",
  },
  {
    "item": 3,
    "command":   "CC",
  },
  {
    "item": 4,
    "command":   "DD",
  },
  {
    "item": 5,
    "command":   "EE",
  }
]
```

The text file looks like this:

```
Transactions/Sec for Group = AA\CODE1\KK
1011.5032
2444.8864
2646.6893
2740.8531
2683.8178
Transactions/Sec for Group = BB\CODE1\KK
993.2360
2652.8784
3020.2740
2956.5260
3015.5910
Transactions/Sec for Group = CC\CODE1\KK
1179.5766
3271.5700
4588.2059
4174.6358
4452.6785
Transactions/Sec for Group = DD\CODE1\KK
1112.2567
3147.1466
4014.8404
3913.3806
3939.0626
Transactions/Sec for Group = EE\CODE1\KK
1205.8499
3364.8987
4401.1702
4747.4354
4765.7614
```

The logic in the body of the program works fine. The groups appears ok, but instead of having the list from 1 to 5 from the Json file, is appearing everything with the number 5 command EE. Instead should appear: Item 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, with their commands

My list 1 will have the numbers:  1011.5032,   993.2360,  1179.5766, 1112.2567, 1205.8499.
My list 2 will have the numbers: 2444.8864, 2652.8784, 3271.5700, 3147.1466, 
The python version I'm using is 2.6

Answer (score 0):

Based on your explanation it's hard to tell what you're trying to do -- do you mean the nested loop below? The inner loop executes 5 times, but in every iteration it overwrites the previous values for `item` and `cmd`.

```
for node in data:
    for i in range(0, 5):
        item = data[i]['item']
        cmd = data[i]['command']

    index+= 1
```

Try printing the values each time the inner loop executes:

```
for node in data:
    for i in range(0, 5):
        item = data[i]['item']
        cmd = data[i]['command']
        print  item, cmd


    index+= 1
```

Comment: The only value that prints is the latest value... Im trying to get the first element from my json file with the first list I created from my .txt file (The first group I create from my text file are the first 5 numbers of each group in the text file)

Answer (score 0):

I think this code is your problem:

```
for node in data:
    for i in range(0, 5):
        item = data[i]['item']
        cmd = data[i]['command']
```

Item will always be "5" and command will always be "EE" after this executes. Perhaps your indents are off for the code beneath it, and that code is supposed to be within the loop?

Comment: Is always going to the item number 5. That is correct. That is where I am having problems. How could I fix that loop?

Comment: Move the print statement directly under the "cmd =" line and indent so it lines up with the "item=" and "cmd=" lines and then you'll see the answers printed. A loop ends as soon as you have a statement that's no longer indented, so the loop you have isn't doing anything at all -- nothing underneath it is included in the loop because it's indented to the left.